# SwiftUI TextField not updating in sibling View (with video)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple todo list demo app I built to understand the relationship between SwiftUI and Core Data. When I modify a `Task` in the `TaskDetail` view the changes are not reflected within the `TextField` residing in the `TaskRow` view. Both of these views are children of the `ContentView`.

**Sudo Fix**: If I change out `TextField` for `Text` the view is updated as expected; but, I need to edit the `title` attribute in `Task` from the row.

**2nd Option**: It seems like every tutorial avoids updating data inside a child view using Core Data. I can use `@EnvironmentObject` to sync data across views easily (with structs). However, keeping the environment data and the Core Data store synced sounds like a nightmare. I'd expect there to be an easier way :D

**Video of Issue**: https://youtu.be/JV-jQHpXE4Y

### Code

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.position, ascending: true)]) var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    
    init() {
        print("INIT - Content View")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                todoList
                newButton
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    
    var todoList: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                NavigationLink(destination: TaskDetail(task: task)) {
                    TaskRow(task: task)
                }
            }
            .onDelete { indices in
                for index in indices {
                    self.context.delete(self.tasks[index])
                    try? self.context.save()
                }
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
    
    var newButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.newTask()
        }, label: {
            Text("Add Random Task")
        }).padding([.bottom, .top], 20)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    private func newTask() {
        let things = ["Cook", "Clean", "Eat", "Workout", "Program"]
        
        let newItem = Task(context: self.context)
        newItem.id = UUID()
        newItem.title = things.randomElement()!
        newItem.position = Int64(self.tasks.count)
        newItem.completed = Bool.random()
        
        try? self.context.save()
    }
    
    private func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        // Make an array of items from fetched results
        var revisedItems: [Task] = self.tasks.map{ $0 }
        
        // change the order of the items in the array
        revisedItems.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination )
        
        // update the userOrder attribute in revisedItems to
        // persist the new order. This is done in reverse order
        // to minimize changes to the indices.
        for reverseIndex in stride(from: revisedItems.count - 1, through: 0, by: -1) {
            revisedItems[reverseIndex].position = Int64(reverseIndex)
            try? self.context.save()
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskRow.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TaskRow: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    @State private var title: String
    
    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        self._title = State(initialValue: task.title ?? "")
        print("INIT - TaskRow Initialized: title=\(title), completed=\(task.completed)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(self.task.title ?? "", text: self.$title) {
                self.task.title = self.title
                self.save()
            }.foregroundColor(.black)
//            Text(self.task.title ?? "")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(self.task.position)")
            Button(action: {
                self.task.completed.toggle()
                self.save()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: self.task.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}

extension TaskRow {
    func save() {
        try? self.context.save()
        print("SAVE - TaskRow")
    }
}
```

**TaskDetail.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskDetail: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    @State private var title: String
    
    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        self._title = State(initialValue: task.title ?? "")
        print("INIT - TaskDetail Initialized: title=\(title), completed=\(task.completed)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField(self.title, text: self.$title) {
                    self.task.title = self.title
                    self.save()
                }.foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    self.task.completed.toggle()
                    self.save()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: self.task.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

extension TaskDetail {
    func save() {
        try? self.context.save()
        print("SAVE - TaskDetail")
    }
}
```

**Core Data Model of `Task`**
[image: Core Data Model]

### Edit

This has to do with the 'PlaceHolder' text (first argument) within the `TextField`. If I modify the `Task` in `TaskDetail` and then navigate back to `ContentView` it doesn't appear to update. But, if I remove the text in the row (highlight, backspace) the 'PlaceHolder' text contains the updated value.

What's strange is that exiting the app and restarting it displays the changes made in the `TextField` with dark font (expected behavior without the restart).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Use `@Binding` instead of `@State`

It is important to remember that `TextField` is actually a SwiftUI `View` (via inheritance). The parent child relationship is actually `TaskRow -> TextField`.

`@State` is used for representing the 'state' of a view. While this value can be passed around, it's not meant to be written to by other views (it has a single source of truth).

In the case above, I am actually passing `title` (via `$` prefix) to another view while expecting either the parent or child to modify the `title` property. `@Binding` supports 2 way communication between views or a property and view.

@State Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

@Binding Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

Jared Sinclair's Wrapper Rules: https://jaredsinclair.com/2020/05/07/swiftui-cheat-sheet.html

Changing the `TaskRow` and `TaskDetail` views fixed the behavior:

**TaskRow.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TaskRow: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    @Binding private var title: String
    
    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        self._title = Binding(get: {
            return task.title ?? ""
        }, set: {
            task.title = $0
        })
        print("INIT - TaskRow Initialized: title=\(task.title ?? ""), completed=\(task.completed)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Task Name", text: self.$title) {
                self.save()
            }.foregroundColor(.black)
            Spacer()
            Text("\(self.task.position)")
            Button(action: {
                self.task.completed.toggle()
                self.save()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: self.task.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}

extension TaskRow {
    func save() {
        try? self.context.save()
        print("SAVE - TaskRow")
    }
}
```

**TaskDetail.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskDetail: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    @Binding private var title: String
    
    init(task: Task) {
        self.task = task
        self._title = Binding(get: {
            return task.title ?? ""
        }, set: {
            task.title = $0
        })
        print("INIT - TaskDetail Initialized: title=\(task.title ?? ""), completed=\(task.completed)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Task Name", text: self.$title) {
                    self.save()
                }.foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    self.task.completed.toggle()
                    self.save()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: self.task.completed ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }
        }
    }
}

extension TaskDetail {
    func save() {
        try? self.context.save()
        print("SAVE - TaskDetail")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(self.task.title ?? "", text: self.$title) {
                self.task.title = self.title
                self.save()
            }.foregroundColor(.black)
            .onReceive(task.objectWillChange) { _ in     // << here !!
               if task.title != self.title {
                   task.title = self.title
               }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's fun to play with SwiftUI (I have no experience with it). But what I can see in most of the questions in different forums about `TextField`, the binding value can be created by `.constant`. Therefore, use this:

```
TextField(self.task.title ?? "", text: .constant(self.task.title!))
```

This should work now.

Demo in GIF:

[image]

Comment: Very simple! Would this be considered best practice? I solved it using `@Binding` but I'm very new to the iOS world.

Comment: Of course. Why not? If your question has been solved, consider either posting your own answer or select an answer that helped you out.